# Applications of mathematics to some kinds of sporting strategies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics, functional-equations, game-theory, classical-mechanics

I am a rather newbie maths person. Haven't studied maths in a while and so not sure what things are called was hoping to get some information to push me in the right direction so I know what it is I don't know.

What I want to study further is the interaction between objects/people in relation to sporting events. So interactions at variant speeds by varying participants over different events and courses/locations and surface types in a range of sports.

I want to look at how the impacts on energy and performance are measured.

If you know what field/s of maths this involves or have any good references  so I can read up further that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: to attempt to improve clarity.

1. Interactions of populations over an event/s. If there are a group of 10 participants and 1 changes tactics or style how to assess direct and indirect impacts to other competitors. Will others change by choice or be somewhat forced into another action? Assessing multiple outcomes of interactions.
2. Energy consumed as an impact on performance eg going faster or slower will this conserve energy. How much work is being done(within reason).

PS I am not expecting a direct answer to the question(good if you can) but more guidance into what fields and resources I should review to better understand these fields.

Comment: Can you narrow it down at least a little bit? Even if you don't know what a certain thing is called, can you give us a concrete example to work off of?

Comment: This page looks at batting orders in baseball and applies statistical methods to try to determine what an optimal order is. Is that the sort of information you're looking for? Or are you interested in the physics behind, say, throwing a football and analyzing what motions lead to the best pass?
http://www.pankin.com/markov/btn1191.htm

Comment: @MichaelDyrud Say for example a marathon(though it could be car racing or anything) you would have say a field of 20 competitors. Competitors will have different strengths some like to lead, some like to sprint from half way etc. The courses will vary in scope rise/fall of terrain etc. Say if we want to examine runner A who usually likes to sit just behind the leaders and come home later. If due to a different field he considers leading and setting the pace how will this interaction likely affect the make up of the race. If he chews more energy early how will this impact his finish etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an example check out the project description by Quarteroni and Rozza http://cmcs.epfl.ch/cms/site/cmcs/lang/en/projects/sailingboat .